# How to make a route from current location to the nearest markers saved in the Firebase?

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database, google-maps-markers

I'm building an application that automatically draws a route from my device' exact location to the latitude and longitude saved from my firebase realtime database. It's something like a marker(my current location) to the nearest saved markers in my database. Thanks in Advance masters!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the Google Directions API.

This is basically the call you will have to use (obviously with your own parameters and coordinates):

`http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/outputFormat?parameters`

This will then return waypoints and routes to you which you can use on your map view to draw the route.

You can find more details here:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/intro

Comment: Thanks but I've already do that stuff, can you show me some code or algorithms in these question instead?

Comment: @JoshuaJetomo do you already get the waypoints and or routes from the above mentioned call?

Comment: I'm a newbie in this API, so can you give me detail explanation so I can understand very well. Your response is much appreciated.